# Navigation item color behave like previous controller. How can I fix this?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, bartintcolor

I have a quick question about navigation item color behavior. For example my **"A"** controller's navigation item color is red. And **"B"** controller's navigation item color is default (blue). When I push from main controller to **"A"** controller and then go to **"B"** controller, this **"B"** controller's navigation item color displaying red. But it should be default color!!

***I mean second controller behave like previous controller. Have you any idea about that ?***

Comment: How do you set navigation item color?

Comment: navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .red

Comment: if I don't give any specific color. it behave like previous controller

Comment: And what do you want to set? Color of back button?

Comment: No I just want to A controller's back button is red (there is no problem). And B controller back button color should be default color (blue). But if I go to B controller from A controller, also B controller's back button automatically red. It should be default color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try set this code in your **B** Controller?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .systemBlue
}
```

Comment: okey thank you it is work, because I say: "this back button color is .systemBlue" but I dont want this. I just wondered: " if I don't give any color. It is behave like previous controller. Why???"

Comment: Attributes are inherited from previous controller in UINavigationController because it's a part of the views stack

Comment: That is the answer :) thank you. Is there any way cancelled for this inherit ? Sorry I am new about swift

Comment: I don't think so. You can subclass some UIViewControllers where do you need different behaviour.

Comment: @SwiftTry don't forget to mark answers if something was useful or not for you.

Comment: I got it don't worry